# How can I get a value from an xml key/value pair with xpath in my xslt?

Tags: xml, xpath, key-value

I have some xml that I want to process using xslt.  A good amount of the data comes through in key value pairs (see below).  I am struggling with how to extract the value base on the key into a variable.  I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="/root/entry[key = 'foo']/value"/>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  Here is sample xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <entry>
    <key>
      foo
    </key>
    <value>
      bar
    </value>
  </entry>
</root>
```

What would the correct xpath be for this?

Comment: Good Question (+1). Did you know that the answer you selected is not generally correct? See my answer for an explanation and for two true solutions. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The following transformation shows two ways to achieve this** -- with and without the use of `<xsl:key>` and the `key()` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kValueByKey"
   match="value" use="normalize-space(../key)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   1. By key: <xsl:text/>

   <xsl:copy-of select="key('kValueByKey', 'foo')"/>

   2. Not using key:  <xsl:text/>

   <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[normalize-space(key)='foo']/value"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note the use of the `normalize-space()` function** to strip any leading or trailing whitespace characters from the value of `<key>`.

Comment: <xsl:variable name="foo" select="/root/entry[normalize-space(key) = 'foo']/value"/>
seems to be the best of both worlds, correct?

Comment: @TahoeWolverine: In pure XPath one *has* to use this expression. Whenever XPath is hosted by XSLT I'd always prefer using keys -- isn't it noticeable how the key-expression is simpler than the "pure" XPath one? Another very strong argument in favor of keys is that in most cases using keys is many factors of magnitude faster.

Comment: Yes I do see that now.  I was a bit confused because I did not see where you were defining variables.  Once I started to create the variables this way, things became quite a bit cleaner.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your XPath works fine for the following (equivalent) document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
 <entry>
  <key>foo</key>
  <value>
   bar
  </value>
 </entry>
</root>
```

You can use the xpath `contains` function to get the same result without restructuring your XML:

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="/root/entry[contains(key,'foo')]/value"/>
```

Comment: I should have known it would have been something like that. Unfortunately explaining the xml change to the people creating the xml would be overly difficult.  I will use the xpath.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very straight forward solution but if <key> in your XML was 'fooz' then it still contains 'foo', and you will have a wrong match.

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="/root/entry[key='foo']/value" />
```

This is an exact match so **make sure there are no spare spaces or new line characters around foo** in your XML. Otherwise [use replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458583/is-there-any-operation-such-as-trim-in-xslt) and a regular expression to trim them.