# is there any operation such as trim in xslt?

Tags: xslt

i wrote a xslt code which converts a xml file to a html file which contains lot of tables, one of the column contains messages(very long messages), but that line starts with either of the two words "Verification Passed" or "Verification failed"

My requirement is to make the entire table row red if verification failed and make entire table row green if verification passed

```
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(@message,'Verification failed:')"><td bgcolor="#FF0000">   <xsl:value-of select="@Message"/></td></xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(@message,'Verification passed:')"><td bgcolor="#00FF00"><xsl:value-of select="@Message"/></td></xsl:when>   
  <xsl:otherwise><td> <xsl:value-of select="@Message"/></td></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 24):

Unfortunately you don't say what you expect your "trim()" function to do. But from your description of the requirement, I would guess that normalize-space() is close enough:

```
starts-with(normalize-space(message), 'Verification passed'))
```

The XPath normalize-space() function differs from the Java trim() method in that (a) it replaces internal sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and (b) it has a slightly different definition of whitespace.

Comment: i edited my question to include the code to get the output(unfortunately that did not worked for me). please look into my code and specify any work arround to achieve this. thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, but showing code that doesn't do what you want isn't a good way of explaining what you want.

Comment: I will explain in a more detail way: While converting a xml file into html tables one of my column contains sentences in which some start with the words "Verification Passed" or "Verification failed" so what i want is.. when it is Verification passed the entire row should be green and verification failed background should be red, if no such word is encountered then it should be left as it is..so to achieve this i wrote the code which i updated in my question but unfortunately it is not working :(

Answer (score 4):

> is there any operation such as trim in xslt?

**I. XSLT 1.0**

**No, and it is rather difficult to perform "trim" in XSLT 1.0.**

Here is the `trim` function/template from **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:import href="trim.xsl"/>

  <!-- to be applied on trim.xml -->

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    '<xsl:call-template name="trim">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="string(/*)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>'
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is performed** (you have to download at least a few other stylesheet modules, which comprise the complete import tree) **on this XML document**:

```
<someText>

   This is    some text   

</someText>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
'This is    some text'
```

---

**II In XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0**

Still a little bit tricky, but very short:

```
     if (string(.))
       then replace(., '^\s*(.+?)\s*$', '$1')
       else ()
```

**Here is the complete, corresponding transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     "<xsl:sequence select=
         "if (string(.))
           then replace(., '^\s*(.+?)\s*$', '$1')
           else ()
           "/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced:**

```
"This is    some text"
```

Answer (score 0):

### using XSLT1 with registerLangFunctions

Today, ~10 years after (complex) *XSLT2 standard* released, many projects yet use (faster) *XSLT1*. Perhaps the problem is not only "simple *vs* complex", but XSLT1 is a fact for Perl, PHP, Python, PostgreSQL, and many other communities.

So, a solution for Perl, PHP and Python: use your main language to do `trim` and another usual functions that not exists into XSLT1.

Here an example of PHP:
 https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions

Comment: That is great :-)